# Bitbucket fails to start on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, elasticsearch, bitbucket

I installed Bitbucket 5.3.1 from the terminal, but when I attempt to startup the app it hangs with the following log output:

```
INFO  [spring-startup]  c.a.s.i.hazelcast.HazelcastLifecycle Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities
```

When I attempt to navigate to *:7990 I get a timeout.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**Java Version**

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Questions: How are you starting the app? Is your OS firewall enabled, or is there one in between your client and server?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M, I had to also open the port in iptables.

Comment: Are you saying it was your firewall that was causing this?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M, yes, the firewall was causing the problem.

Comment: Cool. In the interest of cleanliness, it would be courteous of you to answer this question and accept your own answer to make this question resolved.